# How to match one to one data-point based on some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'job', 'eligible', "date"])
df['ID'] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
df['job'] = ['waitress', 'doctor', 'benevolent', 'nurse', 'hairstylist', 'banker', 'waitress', 'waitress']
df['eligible'] = [No, Yes, No, Yes, No, No, No, No]
df['date'] = ['1.1.2016', '31.12.2015', '1.1.2016', '31.12.2015', '1.1.2016', '31.12.2015', '1.1.2015', '1.1.2015']

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

I would like to pair the data with matched job, eligibility and mismatched year (2015 with 2016). And this only with a one-to-one matching, which means a part of the data may have several match or not at all. If there are several, the matched pair will be chosen at random.

Therefore, I would like to have an outcome which looks like this:

```
df_paired = (columns=['ID', 'job', 'eligible', "paired_ID"])
df['ID'] = ['1']
df['paired_ID'] = ['8']
df['job'] = ['waitress']
df['eligible'] = [No]
```

I tried a lot of solutions but the main problem was the one-to-one matching, to get unique match even tough there could be several match for a single observation...

Comment: The resulting dataframe should have an amount of rows equal to the number of unique jobs? Or is it the same dataframe with an extra column stating the id of any other person with the same job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses the `groupby` method to find rows which share `job` and `eligible` values. Subgroups which share the same `year` are then identified. A random index is selected to choose the `ID` to assign for the `paired_ID`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'job', 'eligible', "date"])
df['ID'] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
df['job'] = ['waitress', 'doctor', 'benevolent', 'nurse', 'hairstylist', 'banker', 'waitress', 'waitress']
df['eligible'] = ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No']
df['date'] = ['1.1.2016', '31.12.2015', '1.1.2016', '31.12.2015', '1.1.2016', '31.12.2015', '1.1.2015', '1.1.2015']

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

# Add column
df['paired_ID'] = None

for _, matches in df.groupby(['job', 'eligible']):
    if (len(matches) > 1):
        year_groups = matches.groupby(by=matches['date'].dt.year)
        if (len(year_groups) > 1):
            years = tuple(year_groups.groups.keys())
            for y in years:
                pair_y = np.random.choice(tuple([x for x in years if x != y]))
                for index in year_groups.groups[y]:
                    paired_index = np.random.choice(year_groups.groups[pair_y])
                    paired_ID = int(df['ID'].iloc[paired_index])
                    df['paired_ID'].iloc[index] = paired_ID
```